# Heroku Deploy logs with RoR complaining ActionView::Template::Error Missing partial layouts/shim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting this error in my heroku log after pushing. I didn't attempt to configure postgres so I would imagine it would complain about that [I am not using a database at all in this application though, I am folloiwng Michael Hartls tutorial, building the sample app.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial layouts/shim with 
{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, 
:raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
...
```

this is the github, however, I am kind of confused. I could have sworn I modified controllers more recently than 3 days ago.
https://github.com/lilsheep/sample_app

The entire error log is here:

http://pastebin.com/ZB2av82g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [application.html.erb](https://github.com/lilsheep/sample_app/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb) layout you refer to shim.html.erb via

```
<%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
```

But there is no such file in [layouts folder](https://github.com/lilsheep/sample_app/tree/master/app/views/layouts)

Comment: DAMMIT WHY

lol! Thank you. I wonder why git didn't add it : c

Comment: I wasn't pushing those files! Which is why I thought I modified the folder earlier! I HAD THE ANSWER IN MY QUESTION! Why is git being weird ! AAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH. also thanks again!

Comment: No problem, we all sometimes miss the obvious and need some extra eyes on the issue :-)